# Browser extension that can magnify one portion of a YouTube playing video

Tags: windows, osx, video, web-browser, youtube

It's quite common for certain types of YouTube videos to have the content in some rectangle of the screen with the rest of the screen used as a static border.

I'm looking for some kind of tool, probably an extension for one of the browsers that lets me specify which rectangle I am interested in and magnify that portion to a bigger size.

- The magnification could be to some arbitrary size, to the size of the window/tab, or full screen.
- Chrome is my preferred browser but I'd use any browser to deal with this issue.
- Ideally something for Windows and Mac. Cross platform or one solution per OS.

Answer (score 1):

It is not perfect but as a work around you can use Ctrl+MouseWheelFWD to zoom in on any browser window as much as you like *Ctrl-0 resets*, YouTube also supply a full screen option on the bottom right of the video windows.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need any browser extensions. You don't need any third party software.

Windows has a [built-in Magnifier](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/make-screen-items-bigger-magnifier#1TC=windows-7). Just open it and choose a factor. It's really that easy. ;-)